# DeadLock in producer Consumer

Tags: java, consumer, producer

```
    I have following classes :

    package com.akshu.multithreading;

    public class ThreadResource {

        static int a;
     static boolean Value =false;
        public synchronized int getA() {
            while(Value == false){
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Value= false;
            notify();


            return a;
        }

        public synchronized void setA(int a) {
            while(Value == true)
            {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            ThreadResource.a = a;
            Value=true;
            notify();

        }


    }


    ------------------


    /**
     * 
     */
    package com.akshu.multithreading;

    /**
     * @author akshu
     *
     */
    public class MyThreadA implements Runnable  {

        int a = 0;
        ThreadResource tR= new ThreadResource();

        @Override
        public void run() {


        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {



            tR.setA(++a);
            System.out.println(" value of a :"+a);





        }

        }
    }

    ------------

    package com.akshu.multithreading;

    public class MyThreadB implements Runnable {

        @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ThreadResource tR =new ThreadResource();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

        System.out.println("getA()"+tR.getA());

                }
    }
    }
    ----

    package com.akshu.multithreading;

    public class ThreadExecutionPoint {

        public static void main(String args[])  {

            Thread th1 = new Thread(new MyThreadA());
            Thread th2 = new Thread(new MyThreadB());

            th1.start();
            th2.start();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to understand producer consumer problem via above code .When i execute the above code i am getting

```
    value of a :1
    getA()1
```

Program gets stuck here only (do not gets terminate).

Someone Please explain what wrong i am doing here?

Comment: May I say this is not the best way to understand producer/consumer problem.

Comment: @AliAlamiri : Ok . What wrong with this example .Can you please suggest something else.

Comment: this might help http://java.dzone.com/articles/concurrency-pattern-producer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `Value` as `volatile`
I.e. `static volatile boolean Value =false;`
You have declared your `set/get` methods `synchronized`. This means that they are lock on `this` (the object's intrinsic lock).
But in your code you instantiate a different `ThreadResource` for each thread thereby **not** making them `synchronized` since `this` is different for each case.
Change your code as follows:

```
public class MyThreadA implements Runnable {  
    ThreadResource tR;  

     public MyThreadA(ThreadResource tr) {  
        this.tR = tr;  
    }  
// your run method here NOT declaring a ThreadResource anymore!!!
}
```

and same for `MyThreadB`

Then in `ThreadExecutionPoint`

```
ThreadResource tr = new ThreadResource();  
Thread th1 = new Thread(new MyThreadA(tr));  
Thread th2 = new Thread(new MyThreadB(tr));
```

Comment: Got your point Thanks!! :) . I was creating two objects and created two threads one for each. So basically the whole purpose of multithreading was lost. wait() method was waiting on a object which was not shared by any other thread.

Comment: @AkshuJain:You were not `synchronized` on the same lock.That was your core problem.`synchronized` is a lock on `this` and in your case you used a different `this` i.e. object to lock on